# Run statement with multiple lines in azure cli

Tags: azure, azure-cli

I am new to ARM templates and Azure CLI

This may seem a really stupid question, but I am using the tutorial [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/template-tutorial-create-first-template?tabs=azure-cli)

It contains the following command

```
templateFile="my template file"
az deployment group create \
  --name blanktemplate \
  --resource-group myResourceGroup \
  --template-file $templateFile
```

I am running Azure Cli via a command prompt

How can I run this?  As there are multiple lines

Paul

Comment: Use backtick ' for the next line move

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace the backslashs ( \ ) with backticks ( ` ) at the end of each line and you should be able to run it. Your sample code with the backticks:

```
templateFile="my template file" `
az deployment group create `
  --name blanktemplate `
  --resource-group myResourceGroup `
  --template-file $templateFile
```

for example, the following code will execute in the cloud shell if you just copy paste

```
 Write-Host `
 Hello, `
 World!
```

[image]

There's another way. You can create a temporary PowerShell script file in cloud shell. Paste all the commands there as necessary and run the script file from the cloud shell.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: ok thanks!  I will check this when I get back to the office, ideally I would like to avoid powershell but if thats the only way then fine.  I have installed Azure Cli tools